# IllegalArgumentException using Gorm6 & Springboot 1.4

Tags: hibernate, groovy, spring-boot, grails-orm

I am trying to use GORM6 with springboot 1.4 in a proof of concept project and hitting an issue.  The full project code is [available here](https://github.com/aaronhagopian/springboot-gorm-demo).

I run the project using bootRun and run curl

> $ curl localhost:8080/persons/ -X PUT -d "lastName=doe&firstName=John"

When trying to save a domain class in a service called from my rest controller, hibernate/gorm is throwing an IllegalArgumentException

> Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path
>   [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateSystemException:
>   IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of
>   gorm.springboot.demo.model.Person.id; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException
>   occurred calling getter of gorm.springboot.demo.model.Person.id] with
>   root cause java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an
>   instance of declaring class

What's really odd is that I have a test that calls the same service and passes, so I'm not sure if I just have something setup incorrectly for my RestController/Service.

Main:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main, args);
    }
}
```

Model Class:

```
@Entity
class Person {
    String lastName
    String firstName
}
```

Controler Class:

```
@RestController()
@RequestMapping("/persons")
@Slf4j
class PersonController {

    @Autowired
    PersonService personService

    @RequestMapping(value="/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    def list() {
        return personService.getAllPersons()
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/", method= RequestMethod.PUT)
    def add(@RequestParam String lastName,@RequestParam String firstName) {
        log.info("received request for l=${lastName}, f=${firstName}")
        personService.save(new Person(lastName:lastName, firstName:firstName))

    }
}
```

Service Class:

```
@Service('personService')
@Transactional
class PersonService {

    def getAllPersons() {
        return Person.list()
    }

    def save(Person p) {
        p.save(true)
    }

    def getPerson(long id) {
        return Person.get(id)
    }
}
```

and lastly my test passes which is essentially doing the same thing as the PUT methods in my rest controller:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@Slf4j
class PersonSpec extends Specification {

    @Autowired PersonService personService

    def 'Persist a person'() {
        when: "Person to add"
        def p = new Person(lastName:"Rizzo", firstName:"Anthony")

        then: "Persist that person"
        personService.save(p)

        expect: "Person to be saved"
        personService.getAllPersons().size() > 0
        personService.getPerson(p.id).lastName == p.lastName
    }
}
```

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure about hibernate. But certainly, methods of `PersonService` seemed to have problem. `get(id)` is not `static` method of `Person` class.

Comment: It's groovy, GORM dynamically adds those methods on objects annotated as an @Entity.

Comment: Where is the `id` coming from? or is it also coming from `@Entity`?

Comment: Yes id is also from @Entity

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for 6.0.4 identified the issue.  Need to add this annotation when using springboot + gorm

`@JsonIgnoreProperties(['dirtyPropertyNames', 'errors', 'dirty', 'attached', 'version'])`

Additionally spring-boot-devtools has an ongoing issue with hibernate 5.  I updated my project on github to be a working version now.